# How to call stored procedure with input, sql type and output parameters from Entity Framework 6

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6.1

I am trying to execute a stored procedure that has input, sql type and output parameters using Entity Framework 6.1. If anyone has an idea how to do this, kindly let me know.

My stored procedure is like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procName 
    @usrid bigint,
    @grpTyp tinyint,
    @members typGrpMembers readonly,
    @n int output
as
begin
     --SQL COMMAND
end
```

Comment: Please try this method
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896334(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: there is not used sql type parameter, In this example using only input and output parameters. I need example with input, sql type and output parameter.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to manually build the class - one class covering the user defined sql type and another class for the object... just a guess

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on project Add-> New Item
2. Choose Data tab and ADO.NET Entity Data Model
3. Next->Create new connection->Next->Next->Expand Stored Procs and check your proc. Check Import selected stored proc...->Finish
4. Save
5. Usage:

   `var context = new ..Entities();
    var result = context.spYourProc(params).ToList();`

For output type parameters do the following:

```
 var param = new ObjectParameter("spParamName", typeof(int));
 var context = new ..Entities();
 var result = context.spYourProc(param).ToList();
 var outputResult = int.Parse(param.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: it's process work only with input and output parametrized stored procedure. But i want to use input, sql type and output parameters in same stored procedure. so if you have any idea about that kindly let me know.

Comment: Which type is you parameter in Proc?

Comment: Input, SQL Type and Output. I am to use three type of parameters in same procedure.